# .ToString().ToList() returns a New List<char>

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a Query that searches for various items. But I just want their Id so I used a projection to return me only the Ids and not the other elements of the item. but converting from `ObjectId` `.ToString()` and then `.ToList()` returns me a `List<char>` instead `List<string>`

```
var items = await this.ItemAppService.GetAllAsync(expression,
               x => new
               {
                  Ids = x.Id.ToString().ToList(),
               });
           var Ids = items.SelectMany(x => x.Ids.Select(x => x)).ToList();
```

I would like to understand why i'm returning a `List<Char>` and how I convert it to `List<String>`

Comment: Why `x.Id.ToString().ToList()`? What made you think that you should do that?

Comment: Assuming `x.Id` is not a string already, I think you should have been fine with just passing `x => x.Id.ToString()` as the lambda of `GetAllAsync`.

Comment: Did you mean to put the `.ToList()` part after `GetAllAsync(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first ToList is unnecessary, you want strings, and with that ToList() invocation you are converting your strings to char arrays. So the code should be rewritten as:

```
var items = await this.ItemAppService.GetAllAsync(expression,
    x => new
    {
        Id = x.Id.ToString(),
    });
var ids = items.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

> `.ToString().ToList()` returns a New `List<char>`

Yes, because a `string` is an `IEnumerable<char>` (a bunch of *characters* that can be *enumerated* over). [`ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-7.0) is an extension method on all `IEnumerable<T>`, that returns a `List<T>`.

So the `Ids` property in the anonymous object is already a `List<char>`:

```
x => new
{
   // this "Ids" is already a List<char>
   Ids = x.Id.ToString().ToList(),
});
```

You then do some more shuffling on it, but not meaningfully changing anything. `x.Ids.Select(x => x)` returns an `Innumerable<char>` with the same contents as `x.Ids`. And `SelectMany` adds up all those `IEnumerable<char>` in each of the anonymous objects into one big `IEnumerable<char>`, which you then convert to a list.

I'm not sure why you have used an anonymous object here. If you just want a `List<string>` with all the IDs, just do:

```
var ids = await this.ItemAppService.GetAllAsync(
              expression,
              // assuming x.Id is not already a string
              x => x.Id.ToString()
          ).ToList();
```